# Linux - Feature Test Macros and Dynamic Linking

Tags: c, linux, gcc, dynamic-linking, c-standard-library

The C standard library includes a method, strerror_r (https://linux.die.net/man/3/strerror_r).

Depending on the "feature test macros" defined at compilation time, and compiling vs the GNU standard headers, one of two definitions gets included:

> int strerror_r(int errnum, char *buf, size_t buflen);
> /* XSI-compliant */
>
> char *strerror_r(int errnum, char *buf, size_t buflen);
> /* GNU-specific */
>
> The XSI-compliant version of strerror_r() is provided if:
> (_POSIX_C_SOURCE >= 200112L || _XOPEN_SOURCE >= 600) && ! _GNU_SOURCE
> Otherwise, the GNU-specific version is provided.

Assuming I'm dynamically linking my application vs. the standard library, how does the linker correctly link vs. the proper definition of the function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of them is actually called `__xpg_strerror_r` and is redirected to be used as `strerror_r` if needed, see:
https://code.woboq.org/userspace/glibc/string/string.h.html#409

Comment: Okay.  That makes sense.  I knew that the linker had no knowledge of return types (or parameter types, even) so I was wondering if there was some sort of "meta" magic.   But defining the methods with different names makes a lot of sense.  Thanks.